# How to get category specific likes for a facebook user using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm pretty new at this. I was playing with the Facebook Graph API and was able to pull all my LIKES using the call

`$all_likes = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token='.[access_token]));`

Now when I display these, they have a field called **category** which has different values like **TV Show**, **Book**, **Public Figure** etc.

So my question is how do I get category specific likes - for instance I just want to fetch **ALL the BOOKS that I LIKE**

Obviously its possible to fetch all the likes and store them on the server side and work on it but the LIKES list is too huge for certain users and it doesn't make sense to pull everything if you just want to show a certain category.

I feel like I'm missing something.
If its not possible through the graph API call, then even a FQL solution is welcome.
Thanks for your time

**R**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FQL, just like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006999/in-facebook-graph-api-how-to-find-which-all-of-your-friends-like-a-particular-boo/5008666#5008666):

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND type="MOVIE"
```

Comment: [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) is not supported now I guess